# How can I configure docker logging to conditionally send to CloudWatch?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following in a docker-compose.yml

```
  web:
    image: my_web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.docker
    container_name: my_web
    networks:
      - front
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - wwwlogs:/var/logs/www
    env_file:
      - ${SERVICE_ENVIRONMENT}.env
    links:
      - revproxy
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: my-web-group
        awslogs-region: us-east-1
        awslogs-stream-prefix: my-web
```

This works fine in production, and sends everything off to CloudWatch as expected.  However I'm not clear how this is supposed to work when I want to use the same docker file locally (do not send to AWS, just log to STDOUT/STDERR), and in staging (where I want to send to a different awslogs-group/-prefix).

Any thoughts?  In general I'm not a fan of having separate docker files for each environment - duplicated code entry increases the likely hood that something will get missed or not maintained properly.  But Docker seems to have limited ability to conditionally provision things.

Comment: what about creating a shell script which will create your docker-compose.yml based on a template and few conditions based on environment, then it will run the docker-compose up. In general for these kinds of scenarios, we use configuration tools like Ansible and chef which create a file from a template with different values based on the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of limitation in docker that you can't specify multiple logging drivers. It will be more complicated sending to multiple destinations with a single docker-compose file as it's not supported by docker but it's doable.

For example, you can use the [Fluentd logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/) and you will have to start a separate sidecar container for [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/). Then on your configs, you can create a [routing rule](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/routing-examples) based on the environment. You can say dev routes to 'stdout' and prod routes to 'awslogs' using something like the [fluentd CloudWatch logs plugin](https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-cloudwatch-logs).

[This is](https://medium.com/@commondream/full-featured-development-logging-with-docker-compose-fluentd-elasticsearch-and-grafana-ce3bec720dd9) another example on how to configure Fluentd with docker-compose.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this, as I think it's correct, I'm just really disappointed in docker.  I want golden config files that aren't modified by scripts before deploying to different environments, and it feels wrong to me to include a sidecar for something that I think is a pretty standard use case.  Maybe it's really a criticism of the awslogs driver - it should have an option to run in a non-connected environment and dump to file/stdout.  Anyway "you can't specify multiple logging drivers" I think is the right answer.